# SonarQube: Registering symbol: 'a' twice in the same scope

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am integrating Sonar into one of our Java projects and experience strange errors that I have never encountered before:

```
 ERROR: Unable to create symbol table for : src/main/java/.../Challenge.java
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registering symbol: 'a' twice in the same scope
```

The server is SonarQube 5.6.6 (with SonarJava plugin 4.8.0.9441 installed), the code is compiled with Java 1.6 and Java 1.8 is used for the SonarQube Scanner 2.7. There are about 2000 *.java source files in the project and this error happens during the analysis of just a handful of the files. Some files that cause this error are as simple as this one:

```
import com.isprint.accessmatrix.serviceapi.ServicePreAutheResult;

public class Challenge {
    private final ServicePreAutheResult preAuthResult;

    Challenge(ServicePreAutheResult preAuthResult) {
        this.preAuthResult = preAuthResult;
    }

    ServicePreAutheResult getPreAuthResult() {
        return preAuthResult;
    }
}
```

For some files, this error causes the analysis to fail and abort while in some other cases, the analysis proceeds and the results are successfully uploaded.

So far I was only able to solve the problem by excluding the problematic files. Any better solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of the SonarJava analyzer ? Do you have any obfuscation going on in your depedencies or bytecode weaving ? This error is raised when two symbols in the same scope have the same name ('a' in this case) and, as you pointed out it does not seem to happen in the source (would not compile) so it might come from bytecode .

Comment: The sonar scanner 2.7 is used and I am not aware of any obfuscation going on. Are you suggesting that excluding some of the dependencies might solve this problem?

By the way: what exactly is the 'scope' and what is 'a' in the above Challenge.java class?

Comment: This is the scanner version. What is the version of SonarJava analyzer installed on your server ? Problem comes from one of the class compiled and used (directly or indirectly) from the Challenge code. And here the problem does not lie _directly_ in the Challenge class : somewhere in the bytecode used by this class there is a symbol named 'a' which is defined twice in the same scope (a scope is a region of the program where a name is valid, a method, a block, a class)

Comment: I updated the question with the SonarJava plugin version 4.8.0.9441 that is installed on the server. And thanks for the explanation, I'll have a closer look at the dependencies of that class...

Comment: you should put your comment into an answer then i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised when two symbols in the same scope have the same name ('a' in this case) and, as you pointed out it does not seem to happen in the source (would not compile) so it might come from bytecode.

Problem comes from one of the class compiled and used (directly or indirectly) from the Challenge code. And here the problem does not lie directly in the Challenge class : somewhere in the bytecode used by this class there is a symbol named 'a' which is defined twice in the same scope (a scope is a region of the program where a name is valid, a method, a block, a class)

Comment: You were right, the problem in fact came from a binary containing obfuscated code. After excluding that JAR file, the errors were gone.